# How to read a file from JAR using NIO?

Tags: java, jar, nio

Reading a file from the executable JAR file itself using ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(...) is a known concept to me, but how would I do the same using Java NIO?

The target is to have a function as follows:

```
static String readFullyFromJar(String filename) {
    final Path path = Paths.get(Main.class.getResource(fileName).toURI());
    final byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    return new String(bytes, CHARSET_ASCII);
}
```

While this works fine in the IDE, I get a

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:171))
```

when I try this with the real JAR, even though the target file is in the correct place.

Comment: Because NIO and because it has "readAllBytes" and because I can't get it to work, even though it should.

Comment: The point is that I do not understand NIO enough to do this simple task even though it should be possible. The concept is called "learning"

Comment: I only know readFully of DataInputStream, that one however does something different than Files.readAllBytes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that my code above is actually correct, the issue is within Java itself.

According to this [Bug ID](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7156873), Java is not properly using the ZipFileSystemProvider as it should. Supposed to be fixed in Java 8. (My actual problem is described in this [duplicate report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7181278))

Comment: So what did you do instead? The question isn't answered yet.

Comment: I waited for Java 8, aaaaand it's out. ;)

Comment: And how to do it in an Java 7 environment :( ?

Comment: `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(...)` as in the question. ;)